# Does uncertainty exist without consciousness?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction

How can uncertainty exist without conscious beings calling something uncertain? When you look at the uncertainty principle, it only makes sense if consciousness collapses, disturbs, interfere's with the evolution of the wave function. You can call it whatever you want to, but consciousness seems to play a big role.

This could be because a conscious observer has a choice as to which observable they will measure. This goes to the heart of the brilliant free will theorem. If a measurement occured without consciousness, why would there be any uncertainty? Uncertainty describes the state of the conscious observer and what observable will be measured. So consciousness interfere's with the evolution of a deterministic wave function. There's no other object outside of human consciousness that can choose which observable they're going to measure whether it's spin or angular momentum.

How can a measurement be uncertain without consciousness?

Comment: That's exactly the same question as "Does a falling tree in the forrest make a sound when there is nobody there to listen?". A tree falling and a measurement process are both open, they both leave lasting physical consequences that can't be undone. Why do we have to attach an undefined and untestable philosophical concept to either? We don't and we do not use it in quantum mechanics, at all.

Comment: I don't know who keeps promulgating the idea that "consciousness" is involved in physics, but you should stop listening to them. Consciousness is hardly well defined even by those who "study" it, and those people are not physicists, since it is a metaphysical concept outside the domain of empirical science as we know it.

Comment: I would think that this is raised because of word. Certain and uncertain are frequently used in daily communication for an object with consciousness. The uncertainty used in this context is different so you need to read it in context. I think the word "uncertainty" here is randomness. Randomness can exist without consciousness. And if a conscious observer tries to measure this quantity, he will be uncertain.

Comment: @user115350: Uncertainty is not randomness. Physicists clearly differentiate between quantum processes which are uncertain, when subjected to measurements, and random processes, which behave very differently.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any reference for me to read?

Comment: @user115350: About the difference between uncertainty and randomness? I wouldn't know where to start, they are certainly filling different sections of the library. I think the easiest example is a random walk because there is a very interesting relationship between Brownian motion and the Schroedinger equation, which are very similar, if we allow for a Wick rotation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick_rotation). A free particle is like a random walk in complex time, however, the wavefunction solution of the Schroedinger equation can be time reversed, the random walk can not be.

Comment: What's the key point? Is it time reversal? This is not convincing.

Comment: Not mainstream physics LOL? This is a joke right? First off the free will theorem is main stream Physics. It's been debated for years. Secondly experiment after experiment shows the death of local realism as reported in Nature back in 2007. Of course those people complain because they can't respond or refute what I'm saying.

Comment: Here's more about the free will theorem. The free will theorem of John H. Conway and Simon B. Kochen states that, if we have a free will in the sense that our choices are not a function of the past, then, subject to certain assumptions, so must some elementary particles. Conway and Kochen's paper was published in Foundations of Physics in 2006.[1] They published a stronger version of the theorem in 2009.[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_will_theorem#cite_note-Later-2 This is main stream physics.

Comment: You also have the Kochen-Specker theorem. To claim this isn't mainstream physics is IDIOTIC. "The theorem states that, given the axioms, if the two experimenters in question are free to make choices about what measurements to take, then the results of the measurements cannot be determined by anything previous to the experiments. Since the theorem applies to any arbitrary physical theory consistent with the axioms, it would not even be possible to place the information into the universe's past in an ad hoc way. The argument proceeds from the Kochen-Specker theorem.

Comment: You also have recent Scientific experiments that show reality doesn't exist until measured as was shown by the free will theorem and Kochen-Specker. "Experiment suggests that reality doesn't exist until it is measured" http://www.gizmag.com/quantum-theory-reality-anu/37866/ Everything I have said has to do with Mainstream physics. Nature was talking about the death of local realism in 2007. "Quantum physics: Death by experiment for local realism" http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v526/n7575/full/nature15631.html People debating can't refute anything I'm saying so they cry and complain

Answer (score 4):

The uncertainty of quantum mechanics does not refer to the uncertainty in the mind of a scientist (human or otherwise). The uncertainty is inherent in the system under observation. Say we are trying to measure the position and velocity of an electron. The uncertainty principle does not limit the quality of measurement we can make of the electron. The uncertainty principle limits the definiteness of the electron's position and velocity. In other words, the electron simply does not have a well-defined position and velocity, so there is no way to measure them. It's a trade-off, in order to have a well-defined position, an electron must give up having a well-defined velocity[1]--and vice versa. The information about the exact state of the electron's velocity and position simply does not exist.

An analogy: in order for a sound to have a well-defined pitch, you must be able to hear it for several periods in order to accurately determine the wavelength. This sound does not have a well-defined time of occurrence because it lasts for a long time. In order to have a well-defined time of occurrence, the sound must be shorter in duration. But, the shorter duration sound does not have a well-defined pitch. In fact, sounds with the shortest durations, like a hand claps, release sounds containing a broad range of frequencies. These sounds do not have a well-defined pitch.

This analogy is particular apt because the math relating sound duration to pitch definiteness is nearly identical to the relation between a particles position and its velocity.

[1] Don't anthropomorphize electrons. They hate that.

Comment: +1 for [1]. Can I steal your material occasionally?

Comment: Uncertainty is inherent in the system and this is the point of the free will theorem. Like I said, the wave function evolves in a determinstic way until it comes up against the choice of the conscious observer. It's like if I have an ace and a king in my hand. The outcomes are certain, either I lay down an ace or a king but which one I will lay down is uncertain and has the probability of a coin flip. You can't have uncertainty without the free choice of the conscious observer.

Comment: @CuriousOne Go ahead. Very little of what I write or say is original (especially the humor).

Comment: Nothing of what I write is, but I try to ask for permission or cite the source. :-)

Comment: @user46759 You are conflating a number of different ideas: the Heisenberg uncertainty principle, hidden variables, and Conway and Kochen's (I assume) free will theorem, so it's a little difficult to follow your argument. In any case, always be wary of physicists making philosophical assertions. Most physicists don't have respect for the subject (c.f. Hawking, Tyson, Feynman) and so make ignorant statements--like Conway and Kochen conflating unpredictability and free will.

Comment: I'm not conflating anything. The free will theorem and the fact local realism is dead destroys any notion of an objective universe. Like Heisenberg said, Plato wins on this one. The wave function evolves in a deterministic way and has to accomodate the free choice of the conscious observer. Like Conway said, the experimenter has the freedom to choose which observable to measure. There's nothing else that has this choice. Just human consciousness.

Comment: @user46759 every living thing chooses , reduces its entropy etc. physics is not about living things.  In contrast there are continuous interactions of non living things and this is what physics models . moon with ocean, apples falling, electrons in vacuum tubes,  proton proton in LHC. This is not a physics question.

Comment: @user46759: Neither the free will theorem nor local realism are physics to begin with. They are philosophical notions that some physicists are mistaking for physics. Even so they certainly don't mean what you think they mean and they would not impact consciousness, at all, since the only conscious beings we know aren't quantum mechanical, to begin with. Your mind can not exist in two states at once, which is exactly the reason why so many people are having problems with quantum mechanics. They just don't "grok" it and wish themselves back into the realm of the kindergarten version of physics.

Comment: @annv sure it's a physics question and goes to the heart of the free will theorem and recent experiments that show reality doesn't exist until measured. "Experiment suggests that reality doesn't exist until it is measured" http://www.gizmag.com/quantum-theory-reality-anu/37866/  Exactly what Conway and Kochen said.

Comment: @user46759: In that case you won't mind answering my question of what numerical difference arises in the scattering process of an atom depending on whether it's in a spectrometer of a physicist vs. illuminated by the light from a star. I am listening. But what you are saying is that Conway and Koch are basically saying that trees can't be falling in the forrest, because nobody is listening, right? :-)

Comment: @CuriousOne of course they're physics. You can't dictate what's physics and what's no physics based on your belief. Nature was talking about the death of local realism back in 2007. "Quantum physics: Death by experiment for local realism" http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v526/n7575/full/nature15631.html Subsequent experiments have buried any notion of local realism.

Comment: @user46759: Physics is defined fairly well by the scientific method. It is not defined by what physicists do. I, for instance, go to the grocery store a couple times a week, but I would certainly not call that physics. Please answer my question about the atomic scattering and how it matters where it happens. JFYI: I have not participated in a single experiment in which local realism has played any role whatsoever. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Any interaction conveys "information" from one particle to another about its state. That doesn't require anything as involved as consciousness: if a photon interacts with an electron, and that electron is knocked out, the remaining electrons will rearrange themselves to lower their energy. What sequence of events (and therefore, what photon emissions) will occur is not knowable on a per-atom basis: but if a particular transition occurs, the photon emitted *will* have the corresponding energy. At such an event, you might say that the universe "observed" things - without consciousness needed. The uncertainty existed until the higher states decayed; at that point we say the wave function collapsed. But no consciousness was involved.

Comment: What uncertainty existed? There isn't any uncertainty without consciousness and again this goes to the heart of the free will theorem. The wave function evolves in a deterministic way. Uncertainty occurs because the conscious observer has a choice as to which observable they will measure. Humans consciousness is the only thing that has this choice.

Comment: @user46759: How would the measured system know that it is being measured by e.g. photons emitted by a machine built by a conscious being vs. photons emitted by a star? What difference would it make to it? How are you going to quantify that difference? If you can't quantify it, why would it be science?

Comment: @user46759: I expect there are religious reasons for your clinging to the 'Free Will Theorem'. Good luck with that on this site. Voted to close by me too.